# Wordpress REST API won't allow me to filter by author ID when called internally, works externally in Postman

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'm currently making a custom API endpoint for a site that I'm building, which works absolutely fine aside from this issue with author ID's.

If I do a GET request to `website.local/wp-json/wp/v2/podcasts` it returns valid JSON of all of the podcasts Custom Post Type. If I do a GET request to `website.local/wp-json/wp/v2/podcasts?author=1` it **also** returns valid JSON of all of the podcasts Custom Post Type - no problems here.

The problem however comes from some other code that I'm writing, I'm trying to do this in a custom function:

```
$server = rest_get_server();
$podcastsRequest = new WP_REST_Request( 'GET', '/wp/v2/podcasts?author=1');
$podcastsResponse = rest_do_request( $podcastsRequest );
$podcastsData = $server->response_to_data( $podcastsResponse, false );
```

When I run it in Postman I get the following response:

```
{
    "code": "rest_no_route",
    "message": "No route was found matching the URL and request method.",
    "data": {
        "status": 404
    }
}
```

If I do this call internally inside the function, it works fine:

```
$server = rest_get_server();
$podcastsRequest = new WP_REST_Request( 'GET', '/wp/v2/podcasts');
$podcastsResponse = rest_do_request( $podcastsRequest );
$podcastsData = $server->response_to_data( $podcastsResponse, false );
```

I cannot work out why it's producing that error when a direct call to it works fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach to this was wrong, and I didn't understand the error properly. After taking another look at this, I was able to fix it by replacing this code:

```
if($request->get_param('id')){
    // $author = $request->get_param('author');
    $podcastsRequest = new WP_REST_Request( 'GET', '/wp/v2/podcasts?author=1');
    $articlesRequest = new WP_REST_Request( 'GET', '/wp/v2/articles?author=1');
    $webinarsRequest = new WP_REST_Request( 'GET', '/wp/v2/webinars?author=1');
    $expertInterviewsRequest = new WP_REST_Request( 'GET', '/wp/v2/expert-interviews?author=1');
    $guidesRequest = new WP_REST_Request( 'GET', '/wp/v2/guides?author=1');
} else {
    $podcastsRequest = new WP_REST_Request( 'GET', '/wp/v2/podcasts?author=1' );
    $articlesRequest = new WP_REST_Request( 'GET', '/wp/v2/articles?author=1' );
    $webinarsRequest = new WP_REST_Request( 'GET', '/wp/v2/webinars?author=1' );
    $expertInterviewsRequest = new WP_REST_Request( 'GET', '/wp/v2/expert-interviews?author=1' );
    $guidesRequest = new WP_REST_Request( 'GET', '/wp/v2/guides?author=1' );
}
```

with this code:

```
if($request->get_param('author')){
    $author = $request->get_param('author');

    $podcastsRequest = new WP_REST_Request( 'GET', '/wp/v2/podcasts');
    $podcastsRequest->set_query_params( array( 'author' => $author ));

    $articlesRequest = new WP_REST_Request( 'GET', '/wp/v2/articles');
    $articlesRequest->set_query_params( array( 'author' => $author ));

    $webinarsRequest = new WP_REST_Request( 'GET', '/wp/v2/webinars');
    $webinarsRequest->set_query_params( array( 'author' => $author ));

    $expertInterviewsRequest = new WP_REST_Request( 'GET', '/wp/v2/expert-interviews');
    $expertInterviewsRequest->set_query_params( array( 'author' => $author ));

    $guidesRequest = new WP_REST_Request( 'GET', '/wp/v2/guides');
    $guidesRequest->set_query_params( array( 'author' => $author ));
} else {
    $podcastsRequest = new WP_REST_Request( 'GET', '/wp/v2/podcasts');
    $articlesRequest = new WP_REST_Request( 'GET', '/wp/v2/articles');
    $webinarsRequest = new WP_REST_Request( 'GET', '/wp/v2/webinars');
    $expertInterviewsRequest = new WP_REST_Request( 'GET', '/wp/v2/expert-interviews');
    $guidesRequest = new WP_REST_Request( 'GET', '/wp/v2/guides');
}
```

This now works as the API endpoint isn't directly set up to match additional parameters on itself, however passing them through with `set_query_params()` did the job!